# TypeQL Insert datetime

Tags: python, database, datetime, type-conversion, vaticle-typeql

I am trying to insert elements in python into my TypeDB database from a CSV file. I have the following problem, when I try to insert a date in a field, I have the following error

`typedb.common.exception.TypeDBClientException: [QRY01] Invalid Query Pattern: The class 'ValueConstraint.Constant.String' cannot be casted to 'ValueConstraint.Constant.DateTime'.`

This is my code

```
def format_date_time(date_string):
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
    return date_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]

...

typeql_insert_query += ', has opening-date "'+format_date_time(account["opening-date"])+'";'
```

I tried changing the date format to:

- yyyy-mm-dd
- yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm
- yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss
- yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.f
- yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ff
- yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.fff

I also tried to put my date like this in my TypeQL insertion:

`typeql_insert_query += ', has opening-date datetime("'+format_date_time(account["opening-date"])+'");'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't the format of the datetime value, but the fact that you wrap it in quotes, which makes it a string:

```py
typeql_insert_query += ', has opening-date "'+format_date_time(account["opening-date"])+'";'
                                         # ~                                             ~
```

Removing the quotes around the formatted datetime should resolve the issue.